# Angularjs : Service is undefined

Tags: angularjs

i just want to ask whats wrong with my codes here?

index :

```
// ng-app="app" and ng-controller="Student" is already injected

<script src="app/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/service/student-service.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/student-controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

app.js :

```
(function() {

'use strict';
angular.module('app', [
    'Student',
    'StudentService'
]);

})();
```

student-controller.js :

```
angular.module('Student', ['StudentService'])
    .controller('Student', ['$scope', '$http', 'StudentService',
        function($scope, $http, $studentService) {

        // a function here which calls studentService

        }]);
```

student-service.js :

```
    angular.module('StudentService', [])
    .factory('StudentService', ['$http', '$q',
        function($http, $q) {

            return {
                getStudentData :  getStudentData
            }

            // getstundetData function here


}]);
```

when i call studentService in a function in my controller i got error saying studentService is undefined! i dont know whats really wrong but i think the flow of my dependecy is right. .

index->app.js->controller->service

Can you help me guys? thanks. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order, because app.js is depdendent on other two modules,

```
<script src="app/service/student-service.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/student-controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: .controller('Student', ['$scope', '$http', 'StudentService',
        function($scope, $http, studentService) {

Answer (score 5):

change the controller inject of `$studentService` to `StudentService`

```
 .controller('Student', ['$scope', '$http', 'StudentService',
        function($scope, $http,StudentService) {

        // a function here which calls studentService

        }]);
```